# How to calculate the number of occurrences of a character in a varchar in a single SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say there is a variable

```
v_Source := 'stack#over#flo#w';
```

How to get the number of occurrences of '`#`' in it in a single SQL query?

Comment: Please edit your question with what have you tried and where it is not working?

Comment: `LENGTH(<your_string>) - LENGTH(REPLACE(<your_string>, '#', ''))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select length('stack#over#flo#w') - length(replace('stack#over#flo#w','#',null)) 
from dual;
```

From oracle 11 you can use REGEXP_COUNT

```
select REGEXP_COUNT('stack#over#flo#w', '#') from dual;
```

Comment: This is a good answer that provide a solution to older versions, +1

Comment: It is also slightly more efficient since regexp is CPU-intensive.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( 'stack#over#flo#w', '#' )
FROM   DUAL
```